# On submit echo td dropdowns and ad new td

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, html-table

I have the following code:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<?php
$count = isset($_POST['count']) ? $_POST['count'] : 1;
if($count > 11) $count = 11;
?>

<table>
<!-- Keeps track of the current number of rows -->
<input type="hidden" name="count" value="<?php echo $count+1; ?>"/>

<?php for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++): 
// Loop through all rows gathering the data here, and then creating the fields below

$val0 = isset($_POST['field'][$i]['0']) ? $_POST['field'][$i]['0'] : '';
$val1 = isset($_POST['field'][$i]['1']) ? $_POST['field'][$i]['1'] : '';
$val2 = isset($_POST['field'][$i]['2']) ? $_POST['field'][$i]['2'] : '';
?>
<tr>

<td><input name="field[<?php echo $i; ?>][0]" value="<?php echo $val0; ?>"/></td>
<td><input name="field[<?php echo $i; ?>][1]" value="<?php echo $val1; ?>"/></td>
<td><input name="field[<?php echo $i; ?>][2]" value="<?php echo $val2; ?>"/></td>
</tr>
<?php endfor; ?>

</table>

<input type="submit" value="click me" />
```

How can I make the fields into a dropdowns and when you press submit echo out the dropdown as text instead as a dropdown?

Comment: Exact dupe of user's other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702863/php-on-submit-echo-td-fields-and-ad-new-td

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php: on submit echo td fields and ad new td](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702863/php-on-submit-echo-td-fields-and-ad-new-td)

Answer (score 0):

First: Fill in the following:

1. Make this to action="mytestpage.php"
2. Give this a name attribue like: name="send"
3. Give these fields types like: type="Text"

If you want a dropdown menu use `<select>` in combination with `<option>`...

Here is a start to learn how:
http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms11.htm

To print your result do this:

```
if(isset($_POST['send'])
{
    print($_POST['youroptionname']);
}
```

I hope it helped you.

Comment: do you think you could put this into my code?? I know how to do the drop down and print i'm just not sure where to put it?

Comment: I cannot put anything in your code, you should do that. If you place the if(isset($...} part of my answer into your code on the out side of your <form>, it should work. Just make sure all names are correct.